# The properties of a group with such operator

Tags: abstract-algebra

Define an closed associative operator # on a set S, if a#b#a=b for any a, b in S, which is correct? 1, # is commutative. 2, S is a group. 3, S is finite.

I tried to prove whether it is commutative but can't figure out. But I think there is no conditions to prove it is finite.

Comment: I'm guessing you mean the operation $\#$ is "commutative"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's forget the hashes and just write with juxtaposition.

From $aba=b$ we get $aa=abab=bb$. Call the value that everything squares to "$e$".  It is an identity:  $ae=aaa=ea=a$ for all $a$, using the hypothesis. So it is at least a monoid.

Further, $aa=aea=e$, so every element is its own inverse.

This also implies $abab=e$, then $aba=b$, then $ab=ba$ after multiplying on the right.

So in fact you get a commutative group operation.

Of course it need not be finite: just take an infinite product of groups of order 2 for a counterexample.

Answer (score 0):

This implies the operation is commutative. First note that by choosing $b=a$, you get that $a^3 = a \# a \# a = a$ for any $a$. In particular, apply this observation to the element $a \# b$:

$$
a \# b = (a\# b) \# (a\# b) \# (a \#b) = (a \# b \# a)\#(b \#a \# b) = b \# a
$$